# Xively Arduino library returns -400

Tags: arduino, xively

My project worked perfectly but suddenly in "xivelyclient.put (feed, xivelyKey)" now returns -400. Any ideas?
The get works ok.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the Arduino library, but I'm guessing the 400 is an HTTP code "Bad request", which suggests something in the content of the message doesn't make sense. So I would look at what you're trying to "put".